# Rails 4 - displaying data from 1, 2 and 3 weeks ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display 3 pieces of data statistics (stats) that were added exactly 1, 2 and 3 weeks ago to various users. A stat belongs to a user and has three attributes: user_id, usage, date_added

**User Model**

```
def added_1_week_ago
  self.stats.where(date_added: 1.week.ago)
end

def added_2_week_ago
  self.stats.where(date_added: 2.week.ago)
end

def added_3_week_ago
  self.stats.where(date_added: 3.week.ago)
end
```

**Controller**

```
@users = User.all
```

**View**

```
<table>
  <% @user.each do |u| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= u.name %></td>   
      <td><%= u.stat.added_1_week_ago.usage %></td>   
      <td><%= u.stat.added_2_week_ago.usage %></td>   
      <td><%= u.stat.added_3_week_ago.usage %></td>   
    </tr>
  <% end  %>
</table>
```

This is not working. Please let me know where

Comment: I'm assuming that a each User `has_many` stats, no? If so, I'd think that your markup would need to be: `<%= u.stats.added_1_week_ago.usage %>`. Also, does stats have a stats attribute? If not, wouldn't the model be just: `where(dat_added: 1.week.ago)`?

Comment: Thanks. That was the user model, sorry. Edited. Yes, User has_many stats on various dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the other answers and help.

Since I am decided to use 14 prior weeks (15 today including the current week, today), I streamlined the model to use a variable for number of weeks ago and a loop in the view.

Here is what I ended up doing.

**Updated**

**User Model**

```
def stats_weeks_ago(number_of_weeks)
 self.stats.where(date: number_of_weeks.week.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
end
```

**Stats Index View**

```
<table>
  <% @users.each do |u| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= u.name %></td>
      <% 14.downto(0).each do |i| %>
        <td><% u.stats_weeks_ago(i).each do |stats| %> <%= stats.usage %> <% end %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>       
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way I would write this type of code; but to answer your question - presumably if one user has one stat (which I assume is the case because you're outputting 1 table row per user despite the one to many relation in your model association), then try:

```
def added_1_week_ago
  self.stats.where(date_added: 1.week.ago).first
end

def added_2_week_ago
  self.stats.where(date_added: 2.week.ago).first
end

def added_3_week_ago
  self.stats.where(date_added: 3.week.ago).first
end
```

and

```
   <table>
      <% @user.each do |u| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= u.name %></td>   
          <td><%= u.added_1_week_ago.usage %></td>   
          <td><%= u.added_2_week_ago.usage %></td>   
          <td><%= u.added_3_week_ago.usage %></td>   
        </tr>
      <% end  %>
    </table>
```

Comment: It's the .usage that isn't working. If I do u.added_3_week_ago.inspect I see `#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Stat id: 5819, usage: 1234 ....` but I don't understand how to show the usage attribute in my view.

Answer (score 1):

@user1322092 has it right, except that since user.stats is an array (user has many stats), I think you'll need to iterate over the stats array (even if it's an array of 1):

```
<table>
  <% @user.each do |u| %>
    <tr>
      <% (u.added_1_week_ago + u.added_2_week_ago + u.added_3_week_ago).each do |stat| %>
      <td><%= stat.usage %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

However, if you only have one per week, or you only want to grab the first instance per week, you can simply change your model (I don't believe `self` is needed in this case):

```
def added_1_week_ago
  stats.where(date_added: 1.week.ago).first
end

def added_2_week_ago
  stats.where(date_added: 2.week.ago).first
end

def added_3_week_ago
  stats.where(date_added: 3.week.ago).first
end
```

And then you can use @user1322092's suggestion:

```
<table>
  <% @user.each do |u| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= u.name %></td>   
      <td><%= u.added_1_week_ago.usage %></td>   
      <td><%= u.added_2_week_ago.usage %></td>   
      <td><%= u.added_3_week_ago.usage %></td>   
    </tr>
  <% end  %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. The first part helped solve my problem, thanks. The second part of your of your answer works great, except... if that a given week does not have an entry in the database then I get an application error `undefined method usage for nil:NilClass` instead of simply a view missing a number. Is there something I can do make it so a missing piece of data doesn't cause an application error? Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps! Try using a try operator in your model to fix that nil class, that should work well: `stats.where(date_added: 1.week.ago).try(:first)` Try will return nil rather than a nil class error.